# C# XNA - move animated rectangle

Tags: c#, animation, xna, rectangles, sprite-sheet

So I'm animating a spritesheet using a `player` rectangle. The animation works but if I try to move the sprite with arrow keys it moves the rectangle to the next sprite in the spritesheet. Here's my code:

```
    Texture2D m_PlayerShipTex;
    Rectangle m_PlayerShipHitBox;
    public static Vector2 g_PlayerShipPos = new Vector2(400, 486);
    Vector2 m_PlayerShipOrigin;

    int m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame = 1;
    int m_PlayerShipFrameWidth = 62;
    int m_PlayerShipFrameHeight = 64;

    float m_Timer = 0f;
    float m_Interval = 100;

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        m_PlayerShipTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\playerShip\\playerShipSpriteSheet");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        m_PlayerShipHitBox = new Rectangle(m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame * m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, 0, m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, m_PlayerShipFrameHeight);
        m_PlayerShipOrigin = new Vector2(m_PlayerShipHitBox.X / 2, m_PlayerShipHitBox.Y / 2);

        MouseState m_MouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        KeyboardState m_KeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        m_Timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        if (m_Timer > m_Interval)
        {
            m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame++;
            m_Timer = 0f;
        }

        if (m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame == 2)
        {
            m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame = 0;
        }

        m_PlayerShipHitBox = new Rectangle(m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame * m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, 0, m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, m_PlayerShipFrameHeight);
        m_PlayerShipOrigin = new Vector2(m_PlayerShipHitBox.Width / 2, m_PlayerShipHitBox.Height / 2);

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.X += 3;
        }

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.X -= 3;
        }

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.Y += 3;
        }

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.Y -= 3;
        }

        if (g_PlayerShipPos.X <= 0)
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.X = 0;
        }

        if (g_PlayerShipPos.X + m_PlayerShipTex.Width >= 1110)
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.X = 1110 - m_PlayerShipTex.Width;
        }

        if (g_PlayerShipPos.Y <= 0)
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.Y = 0;
        }

        if (g_PlayerShipPos.Y + m_PlayerShipTex.Height >= 600)
        {
            g_PlayerShipPos.Y = 600 - m_PlayerShipTex.Height;
        }

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(m_PlayerShipTex, g_PlayerShipPos, m_PlayerShipHitBox, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
```

How to `move the rectangle while it animates the sprites`?

Comment: You have the variable `m_PlayerShipPos` which represent its position. Have you thought of modifying the value of that variable? I think changing its position will change its position. (As a side note, the ` m_` prefix is probably the worst coding convention _of all time_, ogodmyeyes)

Comment: this almost worked, need to add some more tweaks. Add it as an answer so I can accept it! :)
If you know of the C++ syntax, the `m_` means local variable along with `s_` static and `g_` global, I just like to keep my code clean and to find a var's access level just by looking at it.

Comment: @Pierre-Luc Pineault Now my ship can get out of the window/screen... how to fix that? Window is 800x600 and ship is 62x64...

Comment: Simply add an `if` condition with the max/min values (So if X > 800, set X to 800, same logic for Y). Don't forget the offset depending on where you set your ship's origin. And any slightly modern IDE will tell you the access level, you don't need to clutter the code unless you're coding with Notepad.

Comment: I'm using VS Ultimate 2013. And can you look at my code above? If I set it to 800 the reachable area is even smaller (459 pixels) and still the ship gets off-screen at the left and top sides...

Comment: @Charlie that's simply because in your logic `m_PlayerShipPos.X = 800 - m_PlayerShipTex.Width;` you're checking `m_PlayerShipTex.Width` which is the width of the entire sprite sheet, not one frame of animation (the actual ship size), using `m_PlayerShipFrameWidth` should work

Comment: @Charlie aswell as all the other lines involving the sprite sheet dimensions, so change those too!

Comment: @Tristan McPherson Here's the question I asked and got a quick fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387488/c-sharp-xna-sprite-moves-out-of-window-screen I think that just replacing 800 with 1110 should work. Because if I change `m_PlayerShipTex.Width` to `m_PlayerShipFrameWidth` the sprite woud reach the right end of the window and not be able to move horizontaly. If you have an idea about fixing this too I will change them.

Comment: @Charlie If you want to zip up your project and send it to me I'll get it working for you and post the solution.

Comment: But I already have a fix for it, an ugly one, but still a fix. If you really want to help me out look at this question I asked today: http://xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/112880.aspx