# C# XNA - Sprite moves out of window/screen

Tags: c#, xna

When I press left or up arrow keys the sprite gets out of the window/screen. My code:

```
    Texture2D m_PlayerShipTex;
    Rectangle m_PlayerShipHitBox;
    Vector2 m_PlayerShipPos = new Vector2(400, 486);
    Vector2 m_PlayerShipOrigin;

    int m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame = 1;
    int m_PlayerShipFrameWidth = 62;
    int m_PlayerShipFrameHeight = 64;

    float m_Timer = 0f;
    float m_Interval = 100;

    public void LoadContent(ContentManager Content)
    {
        m_PlayerShipTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(".\\gameGraphics\\gameSprites\\playerShip\\playerShipSpriteSheet");
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        m_PlayerShipHitBox = new Rectangle(m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame * m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, 0, m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, m_PlayerShipFrameHeight);
        m_PlayerShipOrigin = new Vector2(m_PlayerShipHitBox.X / 2, m_PlayerShipHitBox.Y / 2);

        MouseState m_MouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        KeyboardState m_KeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        m_Timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        if (m_Timer > m_Interval)
        {
            m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame++;
            m_Timer = 0f;
        }

        if (m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame == 2)
        {
            m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame = 0;
        }

        m_PlayerShipHitBox = new Rectangle(m_PlayerShipCurrentFrame * m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, 0, m_PlayerShipFrameWidth, m_PlayerShipFrameHeight);
        m_PlayerShipOrigin = new Vector2(m_PlayerShipHitBox.Width / 2, m_PlayerShipHitBox.Height / 2);

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.X += 3;
        }

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.X -= 3;
        }

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.Y += 3;
        }

        if (m_KeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.Y -= 3;
        }

        if (m_PlayerShipPos.X <= 0)
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.X = 0;
        }

        if (m_PlayerShipPos.X + m_PlayerShipTex.Width >= 1141)
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.X = 1141 - m_PlayerShipTex.Width;
        }

        if (m_PlayerShipPos.Y <= 0)
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.Y = 0;
        }

        if (m_PlayerShipPos.Y + m_PlayerShipTex.Height >= 620)
        {
            m_PlayerShipPos.Y = 620 - m_PlayerShipTex.Height;
        }

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(m_PlayerShipTex, m_PlayerShipPos, m_PlayerShipHitBox, Color.White, 0f, m_PlayerShipOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
```

I don't know what could be wrong, my window is 800x600 but if I set `m_PlayerShipTex.Width >= 800` I can get only to half of the screen, that's why I'm using 1141. Same goes for window height... What am I doing wrong and why the ship's out of the `"reacheable"` area?

Comment: If its a large texture, and you are moving the origin, you will see these kinds of effects. Try keeping the origin at (0,0).

Comment: But I don't have an origin variable.Or you mean origin of the ``Vector2 m_PlayerShipPos = new Vector2(400, 486);`??? Assist please.

Comment: You set m_PlayerShipOrigin and use it when drawing the texture. I suspect that if you used Vector2.Zero, your original logic would work as intended, though rotation would be off.

Comment: Could I have an example via answer? Because I replaced `m_PlayerShipPos` with `Vector2.Zero` but then I couldn't move the ship at all.

Comment: Done. You need to use `Vector2.Zero` for the *origin* not the *position*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the original problem, use this draw function:

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(m_PlayerShipTex, m_PlayerShipPos, m_PlayerShipHitBox, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

This will use (0,0) as the origin for drawing; which means that your "edge" calculations will work as originally expected. If you want the centered origin, then you need to account for that adjustment when calculating the edges.

The only reason to change the origin is to make rotation easier; in general, you can just use `Vector2.Zero`.

Comment: Just one more question, I have a spritefont which should be displayed above the player ship. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Charlie Carefully; as its length will vary with the text (assuming it needs to be centered). Basically, you will just draw it at a fixed Y offset from the ship position, and the X offset will vary based on length and need for centering. The X offset could be fixed if you want the text left justified.